# Julia while loop going too far and giving error message

Tags: julia

I'm new to julia and trying to make a simple script to simulate population growth. So at each time-step the population grows as follows N(t+1)=N(t)(1+beta). So at each time step I sample from  a poisson distribution with mean given by N(t+1). I would like to stop when either N reaches a maximum value or reaches 0. I've implemented this in Julia but the population often goes further than the maximum value i define. Additionally any time the N->0 i get an error message : ErrorException("lambda must be positive").

```
using Distributions
function new_pop(N)
        beta=0.1
        w_fit=1
        rand(Poisson(N*(1+w_fit*beta)))
        end

pop_S=10
pop_Max=100
while (pop_S<pop_Max | pop_S>0)
        pop_S=new_pop(pop_S)
        println(pop_S)
        end
```

Comment: So the while loop only overshoots when including the additional condition pop_S>0. So taking this out and using an if statement with a break within the loop solves it. Would be interested to know why my original implementation doesn't work though if anyone's got any thoughts.

Comment: Try some parens '()' around your conditions.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might want `||` rather than `|`. A single bar does bitwise OR, whereas two bars is logical OR.